# How to package Qt Framework on Mac OS X?

Tags: qt, macos

I'm developing an application for the Mac, and I'm wicked new at this - what would be the best way to distribute the Qt Framework so that I'm not impacting an already existing framework, and so that my App.app picks up the libraries.  I'm also using boost, so I'm curious how a simple bundle works with libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [macdeployqt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool) tool that comes with Qt installation. It will copy the needed framework from the Qt installation into your application bundle.

Comment: Typo: the name is macdeployqt.